# How can I install a COMFAST 1200Mbps 11AC adapter under ubuntu?

Tags: drivers

I got a COMFAST 1200Mbps 11AC adapter model: CF-912AC.
It comes with a little installation cd but I don't know how to install it under UBUNTU.
I put the cd in the drive...nothing happens.
I explore the cd and find only drivers for win.
I don't know what to do.
Someone can help me please?

Comment: Have you tried to see if the adapter "just works" without installing anything? Many adapters do. In other words, are you sure there's a problem here to be solved?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the device details from the terminal command: `lsusb` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.